# Where to start drawing custom 3D models in WebGL?

Tags: webgl, webgl2

I wanted to model a mouse (computer peripheral) using webGL, but I do not know where to start getting vertices/indices.

I need some insights.

I plan to use shape/geometry editor but so far most of them have UI's that is complicated for me.

Comment: Creating 3D content requires you invest the time learning one of the 3D packages like [Blender](https://www.blender.org/) or [Maya](https://www.autodesk.com/products/maya/overview) or [3DSMax](https://www.autodesk.com/products/3ds-max/overview) or [Cinema4D](https://www.maxon.net/en/products/cinema-4d/overview/). There is no shortcut. Pick a modeling package, expect to spend 1-4 hrs a day for 2-4 weeks to learn how to use it. Then expect several months getting better at it. There's a reason there are schools that teach this stuff. WebGL has nothing to do with modeling. It's just a drawing API.

Comment: You can try using an easier modeling package like say [Sketchup](https://www.sketchup.com/) or maybe [Tinkercad](https://www.tinkercad.com/) They trade easy of use for far less flexibility so you can make simple things quickly but more complicated things not at all.